# Unable to authorize with a specific scheme in ASP.NET Core 6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I am attempting to authorize with a specific scheme as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

In Program.cs I have the following code:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
.AddCookie("SchemeName", options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/identity/account/login";
});

...

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

In my controller, I add the Authorize attribute:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "SchemeName")]
```

I am able to login, but when I try to access any of the controller actions, I am redirected to the login page as if I am not logged in.  I verified that I am logged in though with the following code on the login page that displays "true":

```
User Authenticated: @User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

This is as basis as it gets, so I'm not sure what I am missing.  I intentionally removed every extra option to rule out any of the extra options I will eventually add.

When I just use [Authorize] (remove "AuthenticationScheme"), I don't have the issue, but my goal is to setup an authentication scheme and use it.

Comment: My two cents. Probably you are actually authenticated with one of your auth schemes (let's call it scheme A), but you are trying to authorize the action method using the other scheme (let's call it scheme B). Have you tried to verify if this is the case ?

Comment: @EnricoMassone You are correct that my goal is to use multiple schemes, but how do I verify which scheme is being used for authentication?

Comment: Have you already try to inspect User.Identity in a debug session ? maybe there you can spot something telling you which schema has authenticated the user.

Comment: In the end, I "punted".  After reading some more, I realized I didn't need to create a new scheme.  I created a multiple policies, which allowed me to manage roles and this provided what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use identity , you can add your  defaultScheme  like below:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("SchemeName")
.AddCookie("SchemeName", options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/identity/account/login";
});
```

And use on your contoller:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "SchemeName")]
```

When you use identity, you have `AddDefaultIdentity` , so the  defaultScheme  has been set already.
As @Jeremy Lakeman has said, "If its the default scheme, you wouldn't need to specify it on the controller."

Comment: If its the default scheme, you wouldn't need to specify it on the controller.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, the code you provided is the same code I listed in my question.  I don't understand what you are suggesting, because I believe I am already doing what you are suggesting.